# Avoid SwiftUI code duplication for different views embedded within a NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, code-duplication

I'm using the following code in order to display a view that works with Vision framework.
The view is embedded within a `NavigationView` that presents a title and a button to dismiss the presented view.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isVisionPresented) {
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    NavigationView {
        Text("Cannot run Vision framework in Simulator")
            .navigationTitle("Sample title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                Button("Close") {
                    isVisionPresented = false
                }
            }
    }
#else
    NavigationView {
        VisionView()
            .navigationTitle("Sample title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                Button("Close") {
                    isVisionPresented = false
                }
            }
    }
#endif
}
```

Since Vision framework is not available in Simulator, I'm using `targetEnvironment(simulator)` to display a dummy view just for test purposes.

Is there any smart way to avoid duplicated code for that part that is common between the two views? It's worth to note that `VisionView` implements `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

```
.navigationTitle("Sample title")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.toolbar {
    Button("Close") {
        isVisionPresented = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just move the view selection logic into VisionView itself. I.e. you do `VisionView` in all cases, and inside `body` of that view, you check if it's on simulator or not

Comment: Hello @klangfarb. The fact is that `VisionView` is a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'd still address it at the source. I.e. why view Y needs to know that view X is not working on simulator / will crash? Get view / UIViewController / whatever to have `targetEnvironment(simulator)` condition so it can work on both, and any other view can load that view with no additional knowledge of its requirements. I did this all the time with camera for example. I.e. `#if targetEnvironment(simulator) some simulated image #else real image # endif

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the following solution leveraging `[ViewModifier][1]`.

```
struct NavigationBar: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    let navigationTitle: String
    let buttonTitle: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationTitle(navigationTitle)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                Button(buttonTitle) {
                    isPresented = false
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func navigationBar(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, navigationTitle: String, buttonTitle: String) -> some View {
        modifier(NavigationBar(isPresented: isPresented, navigationTitle: navigationTitle, buttonTitle: buttonTitle))
    }
}
```

that can be used like the following:

```
Text("Cannot run Vision framework in Simulator")
    .navigationBar(isPresented: $isVisionPresented, navigationTitle: "Dummy title", buttonTitle: "Close")
```